# Python- return highest and lowest numbers of bitlength x

Tags: python, integer, range, bit

What python function returns the range of numbers of bit length x? The min and max value of bit length x will equally help me.
For example, x value of 5 indicating a range in binary 10000-11111 and integer range 16-31.

So far the closest to the result I can get is a random number in that range with the function random.getrandbits

```
bitlength=5
random.getrandbits(bitlength)
```

Comment: This is more of a math problem than a programming problem. Check your powers of 2.

Comment: Consider how many different numbers you can represent with x bits. That should hopefully lead you to the solution.

Comment: Why 10000 to 11111 and not 00000 to 11111?

Comment: was able to find the lowest int with lowest=2**(bitlength-1) but really struggling with finding the max int...

Comment: @leeh0608 The maximum number of length 5 bits is 1 less than the minimum number of length 6 bits.

Comment: @BoarGules yes thank you! this is much better than my solution

Comment: That is because `randrange`, like `range`, doesn't include the second parameter in the range. Your question asked for the highest and lowest numbers of bitlength *x*. It's up to you to add 1 to the highest number if you want to pass those numbers to a range function.

Answer (score -1):

here is the answer:

lowest value

```
lowest=2**(bitlength-1)
```

highest value

```
highest=2**bitlength-1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
random.randrange(1<<(bitlength-1),1<<(bitlength))
```

or

```
random.getrandbits(bitlength-1)|(1<<(bitlength-1))
```

Not commenting the obvious